# How to define an instance of Control.Functor.Constrained?

Tags: haskell, category-abstractions

I'm trying to define an instance of Functor.Constrained, after successfully defining an instance of Category.Constrained. However the type of Functor.Constrained fmap is complex and the attempt I made led to an error that I can't explain. How do you define all the objects required by the fmap type?

```
Control.Functor.Constrained
fmap :: (Object r a, Object t (f a), Object r b, Object t (f b)) => r a b -> t (f a) (f b)
```

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.3.1.1

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds #-}

module Question1 where

import Control.Category.Constrained
import Control.Functor.Constrained as FC 
import Data.Map as M
import Data.Set as S

data RelationMS a b where
  IdRMS :: RelationMS a a
  RMS :: Map a (Set b) -> RelationMS a b 

instance Category RelationMS where
    type Object RelationMS o = Ord o
    id = IdRMS
    (.) = compRMS

compRMS :: (Ord a, Ord k, Ord b) => RelationMS k b -> RelationMS a k -> RelationMS a b 
RMS mp2 `compRMS` RMS mp1
  | M.null mp2 || M.null mp1 = RMS M.empty
  | otherwise = RMS $ M.foldrWithKey 
        (\k s acc -> M.insert k (S.foldr (\x acc2 -> case M.lookup x mp2 of
                                                    Nothing -> acc2
                                                    Just s2 -> S.union s2 acc2
                                         ) S.empty s
                                ) acc
        ) M.empty mp1

pseudoFmap :: Ord c =>  (b -> c) -> RelationMS a b -> RelationMS a c
pseudoFmap f (RMS r) = RMS $ M.map (S.map f) r

instance FC.Functor RelationMS where
    -- error: ‘Object’ is not a (visible) associated type of class ‘Functor’
    type Object RelationMS o = Ord o
    fmap f (RMS r) = pseudoFmap f (RMS r)
```

**----------- TO CHECK THE PROPOSED SOLUTION ---------**

```
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (RelationMS a b) where
        show (IdRMS) = "IdRMS"
        show (RMS r) = show r


> FC.fmap (+1) (RMS $ M.fromList [(1,S.fromList [10,20]), (2,S.fromList [30,40])])
> fromList [(1,fromList [11,21]),(2,fromList [31,41])]
```

Comment: @luqui. But If delete the type declarations I get another error: "Expecting two more arguments to ‘FC.Functor RelationMS’
      Expected a constraint, ..."

Comment: `Object` is defined by the `Category`(s), you don't have to define it again in `Functor`. But your `pseudoFmap` is between categories `(->)` and `(->)` so there's nowhere for the constraint to show up.  Learn about functors in category theory (not haskell) and it will make sense.

Comment: @luqui Another point: how and where to define Object t (f a) and Object t (f a) required by the type fmap?

Comment: Meta question: does anyone have suggestions of a tag for questions about using packages such as *constrained-categories*? [categories] [is hopelessly vague](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370697/what-is-the-point-of-the-category-tag), and [category-theory], while workable, feels a bit off, as the focus of such questions isn't necessarily on the theoretical aspects.

Comment: @duplode. Could be something like: [package.theory] or  [package.application]?

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani Simply [constrained-categories] might work, though I would rather have a tag that would also work for questions about packages like [*categories*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/categories) or [*data-category*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-category-0.7). That isn't really a problem with most tags (something like [traversable], for instance, feels just as adequate for theoretical and practical questions); it is mostly the "theory" word in [category-theory] that bothers me. Or maybe I'm just overthinking it :)

Comment: @duplode perhaps `category-abstractions` or `type-category` or `haskell-category`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout [category-abstractions] sounds okay. While in the past I hadn't been too enthusiastic about the similar suggestion [of using \[arrow-abstraction\] for `Arrow`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267069/2751851), in this case it does feel like the best available option.

Comment: @leftaroundabout P.S.: I have just created [tag:category-abstractions].

Comment: @leftaroundabout Best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds, FlexibleInstances
  , MultiParamTypeClasses, StandaloneDeriving #-}

module Question1 where

import Prelude hiding (($))

import Control.Category.Constrained
import Control.Functor.Constrained as FC 
import Control.Arrow.Constrained (($))
import Data.Map as M
import Data.Set as S
import Data.Constraint.Trivial


main :: IO ()
main = print $ FC.fmap f
         $ RMS (M.fromList [(1,S.fromList [11,21]),(2,S.fromList [31,41])])
 where f :: ConstrainedCategory (->) Ord Int Int
       f = constrained (+1)


data RelationMS a b where
  IdRMS :: RelationMS a a
  RMS :: Map a (Set b) -> RelationMS a b 
deriving instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (RelationMS a b)

instance Category RelationMS where
    type Object RelationMS o = Ord o
    id = IdRMS
    (.) = compRMS

compRMS :: (Ord a, Ord k, Ord b) => RelationMS k b -> RelationMS a k -> RelationMS a b 
RMS mp2 `compRMS` RMS mp1
  | M.null mp2 || M.null mp1 = RMS M.empty
  | otherwise = RMS $ M.foldrWithKey 
        (\k s acc -> M.insert k (S.foldr (\x acc2 -> case M.lookup x mp2 of
                                                    Nothing -> acc2
                                                    Just s2 -> S.union s2 acc2
                                         ) S.empty s
                                ) acc
        ) M.empty mp1

pseudoFmap :: Ord c =>  (b -> c) -> RelationMS a b -> RelationMS a c
pseudoFmap f (RMS r) = RMS $ M.map (S.map f) r

instance FC.Functor (RelationMS a)
                    (ConstrainedCategory (->) Ord)
                    (ConstrainedCategory (->) Unconstrained) where
    fmap (ConstrainedMorphism f) = ConstrainedMorphism $
            \(RMS r) -> pseudoFmap f (RMS r)
```

```
RMS (fromList [(1,fromList [12,22]),(2,fromList [32,42])])
```

BTW, you can make the definitions of those maps and sets easier to type/read with a syntactic extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}
main :: IO ()
main = print $ FC.fmap f $ RMS [(1, [11,21]),(2, [31,41])]
 where f :: ConstrainedCategory (->) Ord Int Int
       f = constrained (+1)
```

Talking about syntactic sugar: with [`constrained-categories>=0.4`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.0.0), you can also shorten the type signature

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
main = print $ FC.fmap f
         $ RMS (M.fromList [(1,S.fromList [11,21]),(2,S.fromList [31,41])])
 where f :: (Ord⊢(->)) Int Int
       f = constrained (+1)
```

or even omit it entirely and instead specify the constraint with a [type application](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TypeApplications) on `constrained`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, OverloadedLists #-}
main :: IO ()
main = print $ FC.fmap (constrained @Ord (+1))
              $ RMS ([(1,[11,21]),(2,[31,41])])
```

Also, there's now the synonym `Hask` for the oxymoronic-looking `ConstrainedCategory (->) Unconstrained`, so you can simplify the instance head to

```
instance FC.Functor (RelationMS a) (ConstrainedCategory (->) Ord) Hask
```

Comment: Unfortunately, right now Hoogle is "down" and I can't load the library that contains Data.Constraint.Trivial (I can try with cabal install if you tell me what the package is called). It seems to me that you have given a very different solution than the one attempted yesterday. Before telling you that I solved my problem, I would like to check how it works on my computer :-)

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/trivial-constraint-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Constraint-Trivial.html

Comment: Error 503 Backend unavailable, connection timeout
Backend unavailable, connection timeout

Guru Mediation:
Details: cache-ams21034-AMS 1559477991 3716549772

Comment: Well, Hackage problems...? can't help you with that I'm afraid!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I spent time reading the classes documentation.About the syntactict sugar proposed: 1) I use Notepad ++ and the turnstile symbol is not allowed (UTF-8 only). I propose the substitute (|-). 2) Following the recommended import list, I simplified the code a bit and applied your sugar's recipes.It's all much more readable. This is due to the last version of the package. So why don't put an allert of new release in this thread?

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani Hmm...? UTF-8 sure includes the turnstile, as well as all other Unicode characters. Right here you see it in UTF-8, which really should [be used everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/). Anyway... I know many people still like to stick to ASCII only in source code, which is fine. You can always just write out `ConstrainedCategory`. But I think the TypeApplications-`constrained @Ord` version really is better than either way of writing a long signature.

Comment: First, thank for the link. Second, I agree with you that the TypeApplication is much more clear. I'd like to show you the "polished" version of the solution, mainly because I think it could be useful to some readers (with your possible further corrections). If you agree, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't mean to make `RelationMS` a `Functor` (it can be made one, but not with `constrained-categories`). You mean to make `RelationMS a` a `Functor` for all `a`; you want `Functor (RelationMS a)`. Also, `Functor`s exist between two `Category`s, so you must define the `Category`s that `RelationMS a` is a `Functor` between. The source category is `ConstrainedCategory (->) Ord`, and the output category is `(->)`. However, there's a "default" `instance Prelude.Functor f => FC.Functor f (->) (->)` instance that stops `instance FC.Functor (RelationMS a) (ConstrainedCategory (->) Ord) (->)` from working, due to a fundep conflict. Define this `newtype`

```
newtype Fun a b = Fun { runFun :: a -> b }
instance Category Fun where
  id = Fun Prelude.id
  Fun f . Fun g = Fun (f Prelude.. g)
```

That's two of `Functor`'s superclasses satisfied, and the third one is satisfied as `Object Fun o = ()`. So, you get

```
instance FC.Functor (RelationMS a) (ConstrainedCategory (->) Ord) Fun where
  fmap = Fun Prelude.. pseudoFmap Prelude.. unconstrained
```

Comment: Now I have clearer ideas. But: 1) fmap = pseudoFmap . unconstrained give me this error: parse error on input ‘=’    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block? 2) As a note in uncostrained definition: "Note that you may often not need to do that; in particular morphisms that are actually Functions can just be applied to their objects with $ right away, no need to go back to Hask first." What exactly means? It is applicable in this case?

Comment: Even after entering "where" and adding FC. before Functor, GHCi gives this error: Ambiguous occurrence ‘.’ I tried all the two alternatives unsuccessful.

Comment: There are two `(.)`s: the one in `Category` and the one in `Prelude`. I forgot to qualify it.

Comment: After your last update GHCi ghive this error: In the instance declaration for
        ‘FC.Functor (RelationMS a) (ConstrainedCategory (->) Ord) Fun’ : error: Illegal instance declaration for
        ‘FC.Functor (RelationMS a) (ConstrainedCategory (->) Ord) Fun’
        (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
         where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
         and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
         Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)

Comment: Do as it says. Set `-XFlexibleInstances`. It'll also ask for `-XMultiParamTypeClasses`.

Comment: :t FC.fmap (+1) (RMS $ M.fromList [(1,S.fromList [10,20]), (2,S.fromList [30,40])])
 :: (P.Functor (RelationMS a), Num b, Num a, Ord a, Ord b) =>
     RelationMS a b -- But, let (RMS r) = it give this error: 
"Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: P.Functor (RelationMS a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)".  Adding FlexibleContexts to the pragma doesn't change the result. What's wrong?

Comment: @HTNW Instead of defining a custom `Fun` newtype, you can also use [`ConstrainedCategory (->) Unconstrained`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/trivial-constraint-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Constraint-Trivial.html). This gives you the instances for free, including also the [overloaded `$` operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.3.1.1/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#g:4), which makes it a lot more convenient.

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani the problem is that `(+1)` is not a `ConstrainedCategory`-morphism, but just an unconstrained function. You need to wrap it in [`constrained`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.3.1.1/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#v:constrained), and also give it a signature so the compiler knows from what category the functor is supposed to map. See my answer.